# @media query rule only applied if there is rule to override

Tags: css

I simply wanted to test a CSS @media query for orientation, but initially the rule didn't want to work. Then I added a selector + rule for it to override and now it works... I'd like to know why?

This renders body with a white background - why?:

```css
@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    bakground-color: red;
  }
}
```

This renders body with a cyan (or red) background as expected:

```css
body {
/*  background-color: yellow;*/
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    bakground-color: red;
  }
}
```

^ note that I have commented out the yellow background rule. I initially put that in there, and it then started working correctly, so I commented out the yellow rule, but left the "body" selector, and it still works.

UPDATE: Tested in both Chrome 107 and Firefox 107 on Ubuntu 22.04; they both behave the same which rather suggests that I'm doing something wrong!

UPDATE 2: Turns out I had mistakenly put a HTML-style comment within the `<style>` block resulting in unexpected behaviour! My entire non-working HTML/CSS file for entertainment value:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" translate="no">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
<title>CSS Test</title>
<style>
<!-- Test based on CSS Definitive Guide (4th Ed); p.1001 -->

body {
/*  background-color: yellow;*/
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
  body {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
}

@media (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Test landscape/portrait media query</h1>

<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code snippets runnable. As is, I'm not able to replicate the issue you describe. Is there perhaps something more to the actual styles you're using?

Comment: My mistake!!! (hangs head in shame)

I was about to post my entire test file when I found the error... I had left a HTML style comment at the start of the CSS. In my defence, it's still a slightly odd failure.

I'll post what I had just for interest/amusement.

Thanks @Etheryte for your reply BTW - it did help me!! :D

Comment: Further testing shows that the HTML comment was causing the first rule to be invalid.; The "background-color: red" rule worked even with the HTML comment in there. :(

I knew it smelt like a "I'm doing something obviously wrong" error... but (as is typical) I couldn't see it.